# How to organize a variable's levels in a data.frame in R

Tags: r

I need to order the levels of my observations for a variable in my data frame. When I look at the type of variable with `str()` I notice that my variable is in fact a Factor with 5 levels. I've had no luck ordering them.

I normally create my own vectors and rank the observations using

```
factor(x, ordered = TRUE, levels = c("low", "med", "high"))
```

However, this time I am trying to organize five ordinal categories in a variable. I have had no success using

```
transform(x, variable_name = as.factor(x$variable_name, ordered=TRUE, 
                                       levels = c("low", "slightly low",               
                                                  "medium", "slightly high", "high"))
```

or

```
transform(x, variable_name = factor(x$variable_name, ordered=TRUE, 
                                    levels = c("low", "slightly low", 
                                               "medium", "slightly high", "high"))
```

Comment: we need a clearer description of what "no luck" ("no success") means. Can you show us a *specific* example of what you tried and describe how it didn't come out as you expected? (At a glance, what you're doing looks like it should work ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I've understood you correctly, you want to manually set the order of the factor levels:

```
data(iris)
df <- iris
str(df$Species)
# Factor w/3 levels


df$Species <- ordered(df$Species,levels=c("virginica","versicolor","setosa"))
str(df$Species)
# Ord.factor w/3 levels
```